# Docker IBM Websphere Base 9 for windows - admin console not working (Docker on Windows 10)

Tags: docker, websphere, docker-for-windows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCBdU.jpg)
I have built a docker image of IBM WAS 9 Base for Windows. My image is named as was9_new. After the image is successfully built, I use docker run command as follows : 
docker run --name was_test -h was_test -p 9043:9043 -p 9443:9443 -d was9_new

It returns as output a container ID, and then exits

After that when I try to open the admin console - 
https://localhost:9043/ibm/console/login.do?action=secure

I get an error
This site cannot be reached
localhost refused to connect

Is it because after the docker run command outputs a container id, it exits?
Or something else needs to be done to make the admin console work.

I have referred to instructions here - https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/

The only difference is, I have built my own image for windows

Answer (score 1):

Printing the container ID and returning to the shell is normal behavior because you specified -d which runs the container in the background. You should be able to see your container with `docker ps`.

How long after startup did you wait to try to access the admin console? WAS Base can take several minutes to start up depending on system load and other factors, but docker printing the ID only means the container was created, not that it has finished initializing.

Check that 9043 is the adminhost_secure port, or try using just http:// instead of https:// in the admin console URL.

Can you enter the container with `docker exec -it was_test bash`, and attempt to access the URL from within the container? `wget https://localhost:9043/ibm/console`. If you get a message about not trusting the certificate, the server is accepting connections, but for some reason docker isn't forwarding your browser's requests into the container.

These steps should help you narrow down whether it is WAS, or docker, that is not cooperating.

Comment: I did not wait before accessing the admin console. Thank you for your inputs, let me try and let you know the outcome! :)